# Are Stockfish "Mate in X" counts ever over-optimistic?

Tags: checkmate, stockfish

When Stockfish gives an evaluation of, say #15, I have seen cases where this is pessimistic, and it subsequently revises its evaluation to say #9.

Are there cases where it thinks it can mate in 15, but on further analysis it realises that it missed some ways where black can escape? Or it needs to revise its mate length wards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not happen. If it does, it's a bug. If you ever see it happen, be sure to tell the devs.